# I want to change hyperlink color when I click on it

Tags: asp.net

I have already used this.but it is not giving me any change

```
a.Grid:visited { 
    border:1px ridge black;
    color:Purple;
}

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text = '<%#Eval("Text") %>' CssClass="Grid"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: see if a.Grid:active
{ border:1px ridge black;
    color:Purple;
    } works for you

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that you may want to achieve. one is change the color when link is clicked and another one is that color should remains same to indicate that particular link is clicked.

For the first option you can use `:active` pseudo class

```
a.Grid:active
{ 
    border:1px ridge black;
    color:Purple;
}
```

And for the second option, you need to use little bit JS to apply the active class on the link

```
$('a.Grid').on('click',function(){
$(this).addClass("active");
});
```

You can define your active class as you want

```
.active
{
    color:red;
}
```

[<kbd>Js Fiddle Example</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/EA9Eh/)

Comment: I am a bit new to asp.net. I didn't get what is function() and how to use this code snippet. Thanks for your response

Comment: You just need to write this under the `script` section of the `.aspx` page.

Answer (score 0):

replace `:visited` with `:active`

it will change it's color as long as it's clicked.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. what actually grid css is not even executing though i keep visited or active